# Работа с парами в методах C++

Tags: c++

Есть метод, работающий с очередью пар deque. Нужно, чтобы при определенных входных данных, метод, работал либо с первой частью пары, либо со второй. Пример:

```
void max3(deque<pair<int, int>> & q, [first or second] ) {
    int a = q[0].[first or second];
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: И в чем же тут затруднение? Ставьте `if` и выбирайте.

Comment: @VTT, напишите кусочек кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Тоже не понял вопрос. Ну передайте какой-нибудь `bool first_or_second`, а потом выбирайте нужный элемент пары через `if` или `?:`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, можно ли это реализовать через прямое указание в аргументах, либо first, либо second, без лишних методов и условий?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Я бы написал так:

```
void max3(deque<pair<int, int>> &q, bool use_second)
{
    int a = (use_second ? q[0].second : q[0].first);
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

---

> можно ли это реализовать через прямое указание в аргументах, либо first, либо second, без лишних методов и условий?

Тогда можно использовать указатель-на-член-класса (pointer-to-member):

```
void max3(deque<pair<int, int>> &q, int pair<int, int>::* member)
{
    int a = q[0].*member;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Пример использования: `max3(foo, &pair<int, int>::first)`.

Comment: Добавьте описание второго параметра второго решения. Я не знал как это работает, хотел у Вас спросить потом нагуглил, что это `pointer to members`. Добавьте название этой конструкции.

Comment: @vegorov Добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно для данных пар целочисленного типа, это просто:

```
void max3(const std::deque<pair<int, int>>& q, bool x )
{   
    std::cout <<  q[0].first * x + q[0].second * (!x) << std::endl;
}
```

P.S. Преимущество аргумента булевского типа в том, что  есть возможность передать любой предикат. Ну, и конечно, без  проверки нельзя тут обойтись, потому что(по хорошему) в функции нужно провести проверку очереди на пустоту